# jQuery: Split divs to another divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is anybody know how can I split divs to another ones? Within divs there are img tags?

This is the current state:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need for result:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: `$('.item img').unwrap().wrap('<div class="item" />');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use loops:

```
$('div.item').each(function(){
  var images = $(this).find('img'); //this will create an array of img objects
  $(this).remove();//we do not need this div anymore, we will re-create it below

   for(i=0;i < images.length;i++){
       var divOuter = $('<div class="outer">');
       var divInner = $('<div class="item">');
       divInner.append(images[i] );
       divOuter.append(divInner);
       $("#content").append( divOuter);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for everybody. Probably there are more correct solution, but Erkaner's answer was really good.

Comment: Sorry, little correction. I need another div for result:
`<div class="outer"><div class="item"><img src="image.jpg" /></div></div>`
What do I need to change?

Comment: @levipadre I changed it: `var div = $('<div class="outer"><div class="item">');`

Comment: I mean the original code is different as well:
`<div class="outer"><div class="item"><img src="image1.jpg"/><img src="image2.jpg"/><img src="image3.jpg"/></div></div>`
Sorry about the confusing.

Comment: @levipadre I changed it already, so the one you shared is actually the updated version :)

Comment: The result is different now:
`<div class="outer"><div class="item"></div><img src="image.jpg"/></div>`

Comment: @levipadre got it, now it is fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Just unwrap the images, then wrap them each in a new container.

```
$("#content > .item > img").unwrap().wrap("<div class='item'></div>");
```

```js
$("#content > .item > img").unwrap().wrap("<div class='item'></div>");
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 6px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/42bdc2/FFFFFF"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to remove the current container from around the images:

```
$(".item").contents().unwrap();
```

Then, you want to surround the images in a div:

```
$("img").wrap("<div class='item'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this

```
images = $("img");
$("#content").html("");
for(i=0;i<=images.length;i++)
   if(images[i]){
       $("#content").append("<div class='item'></div>");
       $("#content .item")[i].append(images[i]);
   }
```